# Map of India with Longitude-Latitude Grid Cells Filled in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, maps, r-sp

I have data for 357 grids for India. with some value at every grid. I want to plot it in R. I use following lines

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.csv("foo.csv")
ind <- map(database = "world", regions = "india", exact = FALSE, boundary = T)
india <- map_data(ind , region = "india", exact = F)
(ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z), data=data) + geom_tile()) + geom_polygon(data=india, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), colour="black", fill="red", alpha=0)
```

But I got a very bad map.  [image]
How can I improve this image? I have seen some good ways at
[R Plot Filled Longitude-Latitude Grid Cells on Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164974/r-plot-filled-longitude-latitude-grid-cells-on-map)
But unfortunately these methods did not work in my case. Any will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you use geom_tile?

Comment: Dear LawyeR, without `geom_tile()` I will get only half boundary of India. I am not able to get the fill plot of my data without this.

Comment: Dear lawyeR, any help in this direction would be appreciated. I am still stuck here.

Comment: Can you provide at least some of your data, perhaps using dput()?  Or make your question reproducible for people who take time to answer.  I am interested but I can't offer much without being able to run your code with some data.

Comment: Dear lawyer, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7TdGA0qFbykUENhRlM3Tkd5ZTQ/view?usp=sharing) you can find the data set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an Indian state associated with your observations.  With that, I believe you can merge your map data and your Indian-state observation data.  Here is example code.

```
states_map <- map_data("state")
fee_map <- merge(states_map, spendstate, by.x = "region", by.y = "state")
fee_map <- arrange(fee_map, group, order) # eeed to sort polygons in right order
```

Then, using my code, something like:

```
ggplot(fee_map, aes(x = long, y = lat,  group = group, fill = obs)) + 
  geom_polygon() + 
  coord_map("polyconic") + reestheme + labs(x = "", y = "") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  theme( legend.position=c(0,0),  legend.justification=c(0, 0)) + # lower left and lower left just
  theme(legend.text = element_text(colour= "black", size=10, hjust=0,vjust=0,face="plain")) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_blank()) + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Comment: Dear lawyeR,  Thanks for reply. My data in this question is grid data. There is no state included in this. According to your previous suggestion, I have provided a link above as sample data set.